# Subsetting an R Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, subset

in R programming, how do I subset a matrix so that I can skip columns in between? I only know how to do it continuously such as 1:4, but what if I want the first, second, and fourth colum

Answer (score 1):

You can select specific columns as follows:

```
new_df <- x[,c(1,2,4)]# Select column 1,2 and 4
```